# selenium python - the code stop in the click function but the button has clicked

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I has clicked in the button, but the code stop and doesnt continue

```
print("I gonna click in the toaster")
site.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[text()='Clique para visualizar']").click()
print("The toaster was clicked")
```

When python click in the button it freeze and the only return in terminal is 'I gonna click in the toaster'

when i click in the button, it disappear and a new window is opened

I tried put a implicitly_wait and not work
I tried put a sleep time but also not work

Comment: Please make sure that you have that element

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the fact that the new window takes some time to fully load, and Selenium is waiting for the page to stabilize before proceeding.
Make sure to adjust the timeouts in WebDriverWait according to the expected loading times of your application.

Comment: No, the new window is loaded in the same moment, i wait it for 30 minutes and the code continue freeze